# Extra space in between brackets

Tags: python

```
if a == ("mode"):
    data = mode(nums)  
    
    print("> [",data,"]")
```

the output is [ 4.0 ]
I need it to be [4.0] in order to get credit
I dont understand what the problem is, I didn't add spaces after the first bracket and before the second one, so why do the spaces appear?

Comment: Do you need the output to be a string or an actual lists/array? As you have it, it is a string without full output  ```> [ 4.0 ]```

Answer (score 1):

By default Python adds a space between objects passed to print. To change this you can use the `sep=` flag.

```
print("> [", data, "]", sep="")
```

Answer (score 0):

Spaces are automatically added to separate arguments passed to the `print`.

Try using an [`f-string`](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/#3-string-interpolation-f-strings-python-36) or [`format`](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/#2-new-style-string-formatting-strformat) instead, so you can create a string with the structure you want and then print it:

```py
print(f"> [{data}]")
```